# How to retrieve the text tab values ordered?

Tags: docusignapi

I am retrieving all the text tabs from two envelopes completed. but the values come in different indexes.
I am working in python and used the get_page_tabs function to retrieve it.

[image: one of the retrieves]

[image: other retrieve]

both were filled from the same template, and in the document view they are correctly filled, but the get function returns it like that. is there anyway to retrieve it in order? or a way to identify the field I am working with?

Comment: try to use envelopes_api.get_form_data() method and see if that works better. That one is for the entire envelope, not a specific document.
(Note: To use this feature, the Sending Setting "Allow sender to download form data" must be enabled for the account.)

Comment: Hi thank you for replying, but is there a property por get the text tabs value, from the return of the function?

Comment: you are going to get back JSON with 2 elements - formData and recipientFormData. both are arrays of tabs and each tab has name and value fields. They should come back in the same order they were defined on the envelope (not the physical layout order).

Comment: yes, but to access to that information there is an attribute isn't there?

i mean something like this:

`tabs = envelope_api.get_page_tabs(args['account_id'],"1",args['envelope_id'],"3")

while i < 5:
    print(tabs.text_tabs[i].value)
    i+=1`

Comment: no, I meant yo use the get_form_data() method not the get_page_tabs() method. did you try this?

Comment: yes, I tried it and it returned a json as also do get_page_tabs(), but what I don't know is how to access to the values.

like this maybe:

`tabs = envelope_api.get_form_data(args['account_id']args['envelope_id'])

print(tabs.formdata)`

Comment: thank you, I checked into the library files and found the object envelopeFormData and it have already implemented this you metion. it would be like.

`tabs = envelope_api.get_form_data(args['account_id'],args['envelope_id'])

while (i < len(tabs.form_data)):
    print(tabs.form_data[i].name +" "+ tabs.form_data[i].value)
    i+=1`

Thank you for everything @InbarGazit

Comment: Happy to help.  I'll write the answer below if you don't mind marking this as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the get_form_data() method instead and then parse the JSON that is coming back to obtain what you need. It would look something like this:

```
tabs = envelope_api.get_form_data(args['account_id'],args['envelope_id']) 
while (i < len(tabs.form_data)): print(tabs.form_data[i].name +" "+ tabs.form_data[i].value) i+=1
```